# The alert() and return give different value for my variable

Tags: javascript

```
var buy = function(sum, arr){
  arr.some(function(item, i) {
    var id = arr.indexOf(sum - item, i + 1);
    alert(id);
  });
};

buy(2,[1,1]);
```

alert(id) would give me the value of 1 and -1; however, return says the id is undefined. Why does it do that?

Comment: It's because **you don't have a `return` statement.**

Comment: I did place a return there previously and it gave me undefined

Comment: What did that look like? A "naked" `return` statement means that the function returns `undefined`. The call to `arr.some()` will return `true` or `false`; if that's what you want, you can just put `return` before that function call.

Comment: And in your case your `arr.some()` call will always return `false` because the callback function passes it also does not return anything, so the `.some()` method will see that as a `false` result for all elements in the array.

Comment: instead of the alert(id); it was return id;

Comment: That `return` was inside the `arr.some()` callback, so it would have no effect on the return value from the outer function. If you would explain what it is you're trying to do, it might be possible to provide a solution; what you've got there really just doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing `arr.some(()=>{})` returns either true or false even if you return an integer or string also it will return a boolean value and if you use return statement inside `arr.some()` (as per your code) then your code has no effect

```
var buy = function(sum, arr){
  return arr.some(function(item, i) {
    var id = arr.indexOf(sum - item, i + 1);
    alert(id);
    return id
  });
};
```

it will work. it will return false if id is null or undefined or 0 otherwise it will return true